# Force IE update / redraw page

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am developing a web system with Bootstrap 3 and jquery. I have some shadow applied on one of element with `box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.176)`

I tested and everything run perfectly fine on Firefox and Chrome. But on IE 10, I got the ghost of the box-shadow when that element size change. At first I thought it was that div didn't properly change it's size. But after testing with IE's developer tools, I found that div size does change. However, as soon as I move my mouse to some other element or selecting different element in the developer tool, that ghost shadow disappear. It feels like it is caused by IE didn't update the page.

So, is there anywhere I can force IE to update the page? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved by removing style before div resize and apply back the style after div resize.